# Check if Registry Key Exists not working

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to read a registry key and see if it exists - I have done the below but I keep on getting the error that the key does not exist...when it does? What am I doing wrong?

```
[Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains\localhost"
strValueName = "http"
objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue

If IsNull(strValue) Then
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key does not exist."
Else
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key exists."
End If
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My bad...I was looking for the Value of the registry instead of the actual keyName..changed it to "strValueName" :

```
If IsNull(**strValueName**) Then
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key does not exist."
Else
    Wscript.Echo "The registry key exists."
End If
```

and works fine now..